# How to remove uninstalled pop os's boot manager

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, pop-os

I recently removed pop os's partition and installed fedora instead but I still get `systemd` boot manager (from pop os). [image: systemd bootmanager] If I choose EFI Default Loader, I get my grub boot manager from fedora. I can choose fedora in my uefi boot list, but I would like to get rid of this. [image: uefi boot list]

Comment: You can manage the UEFI boot entries with `efibootmgr`.